# Hotspot Access Point under Ubuntu / LUbuntu 16.04 with DHCP Server

Tags: lubuntu, ip, hot-spot, wireless-access-point

My goal is to set up an Access Point under Lubuntu 16.04, which assigns IPs to clients dynamically via DHCP. No internet connection sharing or stuff like that. Just the Lubuntu machine which runs e.G. under 192.168.0.1 and assigns 192.168.0.2 to the first connected client. Would be nice to do that without a lot of additional software.

I got to the point, that I have an Access Point in Hotspot Mode and clients can connect to it.

[WiFiSetup1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zhxn.png)

Problem is that i cannot select Automatic (DHCP) under IPv4 Settings, this method is disabled. Thats the reason why i selected "Shared..":

[WiFiSetup2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NQQR.png)

Access Point and clients get some class A ip-address and I have no clue how to change this / how to enable DHCP. I installed isc-dhcp-server and hoped that this will enable the DHCP option, but it doesn't worked out.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I finally made it with the help of [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap)! Here is what I did:

```
#Install dependencies:
sudo apt install git && sudo apt-get install make && sudo apt-get install hostapd
#Install create_ap:
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install
#Make Config File:
sudo create_ap -n wlan0 -g 192.168.0.1  MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase --mkconfig /etc/create_ap.conf
#Start the systemd service:
sudo systemctl start create_ap
#Enable the service to start on boot:
sudo systemctl enable create_ap
```